# Найти совпадение чисел через запятую в другой строке чисел через запятую

Tags: php, массивы, php7

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно проверить совпадение чисел:

```
691,695,696,697
```

в данной строке чисел:

```
691,695,696,697,698,699,692,700,701,702,703,704,693,694,705,685
```

Хотел проверить с помощью `in_array`, но тут не подойдет.

После отработки кода `PHP`:

переменная `$ids` равняется значению `691,695,696,697`

Переменная `$ids_class` равняется значению `691,695,696,697,698,699,692,700,701,702,703,704`

Comment: ну так разбей через `explode` и проверяй

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Ну так покажи, пожалуйста:) Знал бы не спрашивал.

Comment: Вот функция http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php для получения из строки массива.

Comment: @Дима так открыл бы документацию, прочитал бы что это за зверь такой `explode`, поразмышлял бы... попробовал бы... и если что не ясно - спросил бы. а так как-будто готовое решение выпрашиваешь))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну я так понял, решение от Ivan Bolnikh подойдет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать как советует Алексей Шиманский в комментарии

```
$arr1 = explode(',', '691,695,696,697');
$arr2 = explode(',', '691,695,696,697,698,699,692,700,701,702,703,704');
foreach ($arr1 as $search) {
    if (in_array($search, $arr2)) {
         echo "founded $search \n";
    }
}
```

или же можно найти пересечение массивов

```
$arr1 = explode(',', '691,695,696,697');
$arr2 = explode(',', '691,695,696,697,698,699,692,700,701,702,703,704');
var_dump(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2));
```

Comment: я лишь советовал воспользоваться explode, а как проверять я не писал :)

Comment: @Ivan Bolnikh Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

@Эдуард пытался дать ответ с использованием регулярки, но не вышло.

Вот мой [вариант](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/74e83f2555fe0c655c518e04883e11c5da345e26):

```
<?php
$ids = '691,696,695,697';
$ids_class = '6911,695,696,697,698,699,692,700,701,702,703,704';

if (preg_match_all('%(?<!\d)('. str_replace(',', '|', $ids) .')(?!\d)%', $ids_class, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
} else {
    echo 'Совпадений не найдено.';
}
```

Регулярка выглядит так:

```
%(?<!\d)(691|696|695|697)(?!\d)%
```

`(691|696|695|697)` - группа для поиска совпадений с нужными числами;
`(?<!\d)` и `(?!\d)` - негативные просмотры назад и вперед для проверки отсутствия цифр перед и после найденного числа (чтобы при поиске 691 не было захвата части числа 6911).

Результат работы:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "695"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "696"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "697"
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Как Вы считаете, подойдет лучше Ваш вариант или вариант у Ivan Bolnikh ?

Comment: Лучше от Ивана. Мой просто как демонстрация работы регулярных выражений идет.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы оперируете со строками, то можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
<?php

$ids = '691,695,696,697';
$ids_class = '691,695,696,697,698,699,692,700,701,702,703,704';

echo findNumbers($ids, $ids_class);


function findNumbers($id, $class) {
    $pattern = '~(?<=\D|^)(?:'. strtr($id, ',', '|') .')(?=\D|$)~';

    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $class, $arr)) {
        return 'Найдено совпадение:<hr />'. join(', ', $arr[0]);
    } else {
        return 'Совпадений не найдено.';
    }
}
```

Comment: неа http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6c537361db421d17dd9366318d88508be88daca

Comment: @Visman запостил свой вариант ;)

Comment: неа :) http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/310141747d85efa2e4fa4dd0e7d5cccf9e8b3d91 - 691 лишнее в ответе

Comment: @Visman подправил с учётом ваших замечаний :)

Comment: Теперь должно работать.